# Return File from Web API in Angular 5

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am returning a file from web API

```
 [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public FileResult DownloadExcel()
    {
        return File($"~/files/Input.xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Input.xlsx");
    }
```

Which is working perfectly

Now I want to use it in angular on button click

So I found some code on internet

```
downloadFile() {
return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/Common/DownloadExcel/', { responseType: 'blob' })
.map(res => {
  return {
    filename: 'filename.xlsx',
    data: res.blob()
  };
}).subscribe(res => {
  console.log('start download:',res);
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(res.data);
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
  a.href = url;
  a.download = res.filename;
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  a.remove(); // remove the element
}, error => {
  console.log('download error:', JSON.stringify(error));
}, () => {
  console.log('Completed file download.')
});
```

}

But is give error

> Property blob does not exist on type 'Blob'

In below Line

```
 data: res.blob()
```

I have imported

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

What I am missing here ? and is this code right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

**service call:**

```
getUploadedFile(url:string){
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().append("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
        return this.httpClient.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer',headers:headers});
    }
```

> this.type =
>   'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'

**In component:**

```
    /**
     * Method is used to view or download the file
     */
    getFile() {
        this.uploadFileService.getUploadedFile(this.url).subscribe(respData => {
            this.downLoadFile(respData, this.type);
        }, error => {

        });
    }


    /**
     * Method is use to download file from server.
     * @param data - Array Buffer data
     * @param type - type of the document.
     */
    downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type.toString() });
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var pwa = window.open(url);
        if (!pwa || pwa.closed || typeof pwa.closed == 'undefined') {
            alert('Please disable your Pop-up blocker and try again.');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , is there any way to set file name too in this approach ??

Comment: This is a fantastic simple example which worked first time - thank you.

Comment: Wow, I'm with @theotherdy... worked the very first time. Thanks!